# How to get foreground running app in Android by BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am using `scheduleAtFixedRate` in my `Service` to get foreground running app in every 2 second

```
Timer timer  =  new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run()
        {

            chatHead.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

                    if (procInfos.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equals("com.xyz")) {

                        chatHead.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        chatHead.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);


                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }, 2000, 3000);
```

This is taking too much CPU and I am getting warnings by *clear master app*. I also dont want to use timer here... is there any way I can get running app by `BroadcastReiver` or any simple way?

Comment: There is no broadcast for running apps, while what you can do is, setup the alarm of repeating type and schedule it for some fix intervals, receive the alarm broadcast and perform what you want. Checking running apps at every 2 secs is too much heavy, reduce it to at least 5mins or more. Or post here what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to put a floating icon  over calculator.. whenever calculator is my top app.. my floating icon should be visible

Answer (score 0):

> I want to put a floating icon over calculator.. whenever calculator is my top app.. my floating icon should be visible

Then make your top app notify your floating calculator (i.e. by sending Intent) so it knows to show up.

Comment: how to do this  repeatedly

Comment: maybe I do not understand your question but what for you need to do this repeatedly? once you calculator is on top then it stays there unless something change?

Comment: but when calculator goes down.. floating icon should go invisible

Comment: Then when you go down you notify again. See Activity life cycle, hook to `onPause` and `onResume` and you should be close home

Answer (score 0):

**Use Alarm Concept instead**

```
void setalarm() 
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceSync.class);
    i.putExtra("ping", true);
    PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getService(this, 666, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    try {
        am.cancel(pI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000,
            pI);
}
```